# Selecting row from table in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've two different database tables `entries` and `backers`.

I wanted to select the rows from `entries` by comparing the email address of the `user->email` and the `email` in the `backers` table. Then I need to take the `crowd_fund_id` of those matching rows to get the rows from the table `entries`.

I tried the following queries and didn't work:

```
$donations = DB::table('entries')
                     ->join(
                         'backers', 
                         function($join, $user){
                             $join->on(
                                 'entries.crowd_id', 
                                 'backers.crowd_fund_id'
                             )
                             ->where(
                                 'backers.email', 
                                 $user->email
                             );
                         }
                     )
                     ->get();
```

and

```
$donations = Entries::where(
    'crowd_id', 
    Backers::where('email', $user->email)->pluck('crowd_fund_id')
)->get();
```

What will be the best way to get the row from `entries` ?

Comment: can you post what mysql query u need to build on laravel ?

Comment: I didn't get you exactly. I need to retrieve all rows from the `entries`.

Comment: not clear what u exactly want, if you can provide the plain mysql query about what you want then it will be easy to convert to laravel.

Comment: Oh okay. I actually need the query syntax. Doesn't matter if its in plain mysql or laravel. I just need the logic to select the rows.

Comment: It's probable the first query didn't work because it should be `function($join) use ($user)` to pass the `$user` var into the callback.

Comment: Tried now and gives me and error: `Missing argument 3 for Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::on()`

Comment: Getting somewhere, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is a little off...

```
$donations = DB::table('entries')
    ->join('backers', function($join) use ($user)
    {
        $join->on('entries.crowd_id', '=', 'backers.crowd_fund_id')
             ->where('backers.email', '=', $user->email);
    })->get();
```

The second query gives one result because you are using `pluck()`.  If you just want a list (array) of `crowd_fund_id`, use `->lists('crowd_fund_id')` rather than `->pluck()`.

Comment: Getting this error: 

`Missing argument 3 for Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::where(), called in C:\wamp\www\nom\laravel\app\controllers\AccountController.php on line 26 and defined`

Comment: The second query from question gives one result even though there are many results.

Comment: Apparently `JoinClause` is picky and doesn't want to assume anything.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: For some reason, the ID is not the right one. Can you double check it?

Comment: There really isn't anything for me to double check.  I tried this locally and it's grabbing correct data for me.  Are you passing in the correct `$user` object?

Comment: Yes I'm passing the correct `$user` object. But the `id` of the `entries` are different. May be from the `backers` table.

Comment: Is there any way you can show some sample data in your tables and then a sample of the results you expect to see from the sql?

Answer (score 0):

it would be simpler if you do this

```
Banker::join('entries','entries.crowd_id','=','bankers.crowd_fund_id')
->where('bankers.email',$user->email)->get();
```